# Strange PC behavior: Is my Motherboard or CPU failing?

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, power-supply

Yesterday, when I tried to boot my computer (see below for specs), it would start booting for about 1-3 seconds, then shut off for a second or two. It would cycle like this indefinitely until I either shut off the power supply or held the "on" button for 5 seconds. During the 1-3 seconds it was on, the fans on all the components and case appeared to spin normally. I finally just unplugged it and let it sit like that overnight. Note that during this time, the monitors never received any output.

This morning, I plugged it back in and turned it on. It no longer "cycled," but instead gave me a message saying that my CPU overclocking has failed. So I went into the BIOS and disabled the CPU overclocking (which was set at 4.5 GHz). After that, the computer booted normally and seems to function with no problems.

I built this computer in mid 2012 and had it overclocked at 4.5 GHz since then with no problems. This sudden strange behavior has me worried. Is my CPU or motherboard failing? Is there a way I could find out what went wrong? Should I not overclock it again?

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Specs:

```
Motherboard: ASUS P8 Z77-V Pro
CPU: Intel i5-3570K CPU @ 3.4 GHz
Heatsink: Noctua NH-D15
Graphics: EVGA GeForce GTX 680
HD: 256 GB Crucial m4 SSD 
RAM: 8 GB Corsair Vengeance DDR3 1,600MHz
Case: Corsair Graphite Series 600T
PSU: Seasonic x Series 1050 watts
OS: Windows 7 64-bit
```

Comment: You could look in the event viewer back near the time it was acting flakey and see if it shutdown itself for some protective reason.  Like thermal problems.  It might give some clues.  use search to find the event viewer in the control panels (assuming Windows)

Comment: do you check your power supply? the overclocked mother board needs more power and its possible power supply is damaged and cant hold against heavy load.

Comment: @Arash How would I go about checking the power supply? (I've never done anything like this before)

Comment: @infixed I looked at `Windows Logs -> System` and `Applications and Services Logs -> Hardware Events` but didn't see anything strange in there. Is there some other place I should look? Any specific type of message or event I should be on the lookout for? Thanks!

Comment: @infixed Try looking at windows logs -> System. Pay attention to the Kernel-Power source, or event ID 109.

Comment: It may have just gone so screwy at the lowest level that there won't be clues in the log.   Overclocking means accepting the risk of undefined behavior.   I suppose if I had my heart set on overclocking, I check basic functionality, like run MEMTEST86 overnight to see if the memory works OK during overclocking.  I'll admit I'm not personally attracted to overclocking though.

Comment: @BigElittles I looked at all the ID 109 events over the past month. Nothing there looked out of the ordinary.

Comment: I wouldn't look in Windows event logs for power events like this since it seems like it happened before the OS, any all Windows usually says is there was an unexpected shutdown. Not sure, but your motherboard may have its own logs in the BIOS that records power events like surges, etc.

Comment: You will probably have to go into the BIOS and over voltage the CPU to get that to work.  However, overclocking generates a lot of extra heat, monitor temps to make sure it isn't overheating. I would back it down to 4.4 and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Arash The power supply is 1050W clearly that isn't the problem.  Even in a weakened state it has 200-450w spare watts.  It would have to be on the verge of death.